# C#: Inherit from Boolean?

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading, boolean

(how) can I Inherit from Boolean?
(Or make my class comparable to Boolean with '=' Operator)

```
class MyClass : Boolean
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this = true;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        if(myClass == true)
            //do something...
        else
            //do something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to inherit from Boolean? With inheritance, it must fufill the "is a" relationship. Is your class a boolean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private bool isTrue = true;

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, bool b)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a.isTrue == b;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, bool b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

somewhere in code you can compare your object with boolean value:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
if ( a == true ) { // it compares with a.isTrue property as defined in == operator overloading method
   // ...
}
```

Comment: However, I won't recommend anybody this pattern. == operator overloading is not clear to understand, because most programmers consider it as object reference equality check or primitive data types equality check. In code (a == true) "a"-variable will be considered by everyone as bool data type and will be confused. Operator overload should be avoided, I wonder why Microsoft added this feature in C#.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. `System.Boolean` is a struct, and you can't derive from structs.

Now, why do you want to do so, exactly? What's the bigger purpose?

You *could* include an implicit conversion operator from your class to `bool`, but personally I wouldn't. I would almost always prefer to expose a property, so you'd write:

```
if (myValue.MyProperty)
```

... I think that keeps things clear. But if you could give us more of the *real* context, we may be able to give more concrete advice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an implicit conversion operator to have this code:

```
class MyClass {
  public bool Value { get; set; }
  public MyClass() {
    Value = true;
  }
  public static implicit operator bool(MyClass m) {
    return m != null && m.Value;
  }
}

class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    if (myClass) { // MyClass can be treated like a Boolean
      Console.WriteLine("myClass is true");
    }
    else {
      Console.WriteLine("myClass is false");
    }
  }
}
```

It can be used as above:

```
if (myClass) ...
```

Or like this:

```
if (myClass == true) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

while your example wouldnt work, you can do something similar for your own classes to test if one equals the values of another.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

```
public static bool operator ==(ThreeDPoint a, ThreeDPoint b)
{
    // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If one is null, but not both, return false.
    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z;
}

public static bool operator !=(ThreeDPoint a, ThreeDPoint b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ("or make my class comparable..."), by overriding the == operator. I presume Jon Skeet overlooked that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use your value in 'if' statements, define [`operator true` and `operator false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx) (along with the `&` and `|` operators if you want to use `&&` and `||`.) ([VB equivalents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93xa16x4.aspx))

To answer more, I would have to know what you're trying to do (in other words, why not just use `bool` directly?)