# Is it possible create extended boolean?

Tags: c#

So basically I would like to create an extended boolean. The base one has Equals, CompareTo functions, but I would like to create a bool type which has some other functions, methods...

For example:

```
extbool eb = true;

var pos = eb.position
```

or

```
eb.get...()
```

Is there any possibility to do this in C#?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The methods on a Boolean are pretty much complete! The whole reason for using a Boolean is that it simply has 2 values (or 3 if a nullable boolean)!

Comment: Unclear what problem you have with creating such new class/struct or extension methods. Please clarify expected usage and show your existing attempts..

Comment: To help you get a better answer, what is the motivation behind this question? Why do you want to do this?

Also useful, what is the return type of `.position` or `.get()`?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988164/c-inherit-from-boolean

Comment: C# has something called extension methods to extend without reimplementing, I think that should be good for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Wrapper class perhaps?  @Carlo - very interesting +1, I didn't know about extension methods.

Comment: theoretically you can create extension methods for any type.

Comment: question is, WHAT are you trying to achieve? WHY?

Comment: My purpose for it, because I would like to handle a bool event deeper.

Comment: For example if I have a mousclick event, I generate a bool type "Clicked"..., but I don't want to only use if it's clicked or not, I would like to know for example the cursor position, that's why I tried to find out a structure with extended boolean, then I can handle the event as a unit, so not only Clicked, but clicked.Position for instance...

Comment: Do  you really wanted to ask - "how to implement something like [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for something similar to [Control.MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx)" instead of your strange "extended boolean" question?

Comment: You don't need to extend boolean to achieve this.  In fact, you won't succeed this way.  Instead, inherit from `EventArgs` and add your Position property in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure the purpose for additional methods on the Boolean type, but you can use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Example (change the return type to whatever you need):

```
public static class BoolExtensions
{
    public static int Position(this bool val)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
bool foo = false;
int position = foo.Position();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define your own class and override the implicit cast operator to boolean:

```
public static implicit operator extbool  (bool instance)
   {
        //implicit cast logic
        return extbool ;
   }
```

Now you can easily do:

```
extbool a = true;
```

and the opposite:

```
public static implicit operator bool (extbool  instance)
   {
        //implicit cast logic
        return extbool ;
   }
```

This should let you also do comparisons also cast into/from a boolean.
Here's a nice article that explains everything

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93160/Operator-Overloading-with-Implicit-and-Explicit-Ca